# JTextField only accepts one digit from my button

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a simple java calculator. If i press 1 button twice to get 11, i get only 1. please help. 
This is what i've tried

```
private void Button2ActionPerformed (java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    number = Button2.getText();
    pane.setText(number);
}
```

Comment: You want to "append" the text, not "set" it. That's an easy mistake at first.

Comment: Thanks it worked. But it started with null111 so I tried appending the pane itself and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void Button2ActionPerformed (java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        // TODO add your handling code here:
        number = Button2.getText(); // this will overwrite the previous value of number
        pane.setText(number);
    }
```

You'll need something like this:

```
private void Button2ActionPerformed (java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        // TODO add your handling code here:
        number = number + Button2.getText();
        pane.setText(number);
    }
```

The implementation might become more difficult, depending on how you want to handle the mathematic symbols, though.

Comment: You probably meant `pane.setText(pane.getText() + Button2.getText())`

Comment: which would also be valid. according to how the code is currently, what I wrote would also be correct. if he wants to use your version, he doesn't have to update the number variable each actionPerformed, I just implemented as little changes as had to

Comment: Use the `insertString(...) method of the Document to add the text.